# Where can I find the rules on acuiring or training beast companions in D&D 5e?

Tags: dnd-5e

Tonight during our game session a player asked if he could buy a mastiff companion, but I could not find any rules that governed the acquiring of companions. I'm not sure if he wants to use the animal in combat or not, but any rules and their locations withing the PHB or DMG on buying or training companions would be greatly appreciated. All I could find were rules about training new skills or tools and optional rules about requiring downtime before leveling to "train" your new spells/attacks/etc.

Comment: Specifically for the mastiff, you can find it in the mounts section, already trained for small characters to ride on.

Comment: Ahhh ok thanks! Now that you mention mounts I do remember telling him that as a Goliath he couldn't ride it... but as games are kinda hectic with people asking me questions one right after the other some details get lost in translation. Looks like I'll definitely have to talk to him about this particular animal and his intentions... i guess he could always use it like a pack mule...